# Is ImageMagick identify enough to verify that the image is indeed an image

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, security, image-uploading

I use the code below to test whether an uploaded file is indeed an image. (The code below is not the same OOP style found in the php website when using ImageMagick because I am on a shared server and that is the instructions my hosting provided when using ImageMagick AND Actual script will involve rerouting users, unlinking or deleting the file uploaded and more so please do not criticize the code below, I just want to dwell in the concept of using **IMAGICK IDENTIFY** as an image verification tool.)

```
<?php
if(!exec('/usr/bin/identify /home/user/public_html/joteco_test_folder/thisisanimage.jpg'))
{
echo "NOT AN IMAGE";
}
else
{
echo exec('/path/here/identify /path/here/thisisanimage.jpg');
}
?>
```

I tried the following on the code above:

1. A .jpg made with photoshop cs6.
   (It passed and echoed the following details "810x203 810x203+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 32.4KB 0.000u 0:00.000")
2. A .txt file. (It failed and echoed "NOT AN IMAGE")
3. A .jpg file made with notepad that has text characters written that says "I AM AN IMAGE". (It failed and echoed "NOT AN IMAGE")

(In my point of view I think it was a success, but I know that hackers do more than what I did in test #3.)

SO! Do you think that would be enough as a security check to verify if an uploaded file is indeed an image? Or are there other tools in ImageMagick that I can use for this purpose? Your thoughts?

(Pls. do not suggest or mention ( MIME | EXTENSION | GETIMAGESIZE ) as it has been repeatedly mentioned in stackoverflow as useless methods in verifying uploaded files. Thank you)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help you out.

```
$im = @imagecreatefromjpeg($imgname);
if(!$im)
    {
    return false;
    }
else
    {
            imagedestroy($im);
            return true;
    }
```

In addition to checking if its an image it also returns false for incomplete (partaily uploaded) images

Comment: yes it is, but its surprisingly fast and accurate. i process over 5000 images per batch twice a day.

Comment: As long as it can do the job. Thank you @suyash!

Comment: `imagedestroy` is never reached.

Comment: sorry my bad, but its easy to follow.

Comment: @Gumbo so what would you guys recommend to terminate the process?

Comment: @joespina Store the value to be returned in a variable, destroy the image, and then return the stored value.